# Heroku Rails 4 HTTP DELETE method API results "403 Access denied"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

gem 'grape' is used to create a Rails based API application. Rails version is "4.0.4" and the app is being hosted in heroku. Below is the code used to generate the api

```
delete '/:venue_id/events/:event_id' do 
    @venue = Venue.where(:id => params[:venue_id]).last

    return {:ack => "failure", :ack_message => "Venue not found"} if @venue.nil?

    return {:ack => "failure", :ack_message => "You are not admin of this venue."} unless @venue.users.include? @api_user


    event = @venue.events.where(:id => params[:event_id]).last
    if event.destroy
      response = {:ack => "success", :ack_message => "success" }
    else
      response = {:ack => "failure", :ack_message => "failure" }
    end
  end
```

API generated was working fine 2 days ago but currently it gives 403 Access Denied:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
    <H1>Access Denied</H1>
    <HR>
        <FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial">
            <B>
            Description: You are not allowed to access the document you requested....
```

All other API services using post, get or put are working but the one using HTTP DELETE is not.

I also tried resetting the HEAD to some commits backward but it didn't make any change.
Last option would be to simply change the DELETE to POST please suggest.

Edit:
The issue is seen on other apps on heroku too. Is this a change in heroku? Or, how can I get through this?

Edit 2:
To tryout you can use:

```
curl -X DELETE "http://anyapp.herokuapp.com"
```

Comment: That html code doesn't look like it was returned from your Rails app. That looks like the html code was written 15 years ago. Perhaps your webserver is misconfigured?

Comment: Well, that's what heroku returned. Which configuration of heroku should be changed for the purpose? It is something wrong with the server as it seems to be working fine in local development environment.

Comment: The `curl` command works on my side. My guess is that your firewall or router settings block `DELETE` requests. Can you check the logs at heroku, if your `DELETE` requests are recorded?

Comment: Yes, possibly if it is working at your side.
The DELETE reqeusts are not being recorded in heroku logs. I tried through other systems here too but wasn't helpful. How can I have it working here too? Any suggestions.

Comment: You seem to be right. I tried the curl through a server's bash and it seems to be working there. But why is it getting restricted from our end and just the DELETE method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be with the internet provider. The API worked with HTTPS and they are on to solving the issue.